# Dynamic forms Angular2. Conditional field visibility

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, dynamic-forms

I would like to show a field only when there is a concrete value in other one using dynamic forms.

I've defined a new property "condition: boolean" for the class QuestionBase (app/question-base.ts)
My intention is to show a field dinamically when other one has a concrete value. I named this field "Conditional"

I think that I must include any sentence like *ngIf in the  label in app/dynamic-form-question.component.html for injecting a personalized condition, but I'm stucked. 
*ngIf doesn't evaluate question.condition when condition is defined as string. I can't find any solution to define, as a boolean, a expression in app/question.service.ts.

```
e.g.
      new TextboxQuestion({
        key: 'conditional',
        label: 'Conditional Field',
        type: 'text',
        condition: brave.value == solid, (something like this, brave is other field in this form)
        order: 5
      })
```

Then a would read the condition expression for change visibility.

```
    <input *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'" [formControlName]="question.key"
            [id]="question.key" [type]="question.type">

    <select [id]="question.key" *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'" [formControlName]="question.key">
      <option *ngFor="let opt of question.options" [value]="opt.key">{{opt.value}}</option>
    </select>

  </div>
```

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xfDbICjmCGURVk6szrwp?p=preview). The example is from the angular2 tutorial, with some changes.
I searched a lot about dynamic forms, it's probably because I am a beginner in Angular2.

Many thanks

Comment: I'm having the same problem.. Did you find a solution in the end?

Comment: I solved this by adding another property to my interface called condition which takes a function that should always return true or false.

Then in my template i would simply check if it was returning true, when injecting the form into my function.

Answer (score 0):

Give the input an: 'ngControl="questionKey"' or whatever you feel like, it would be defined in the class at the top questionKey:Control. Then on the select element you can add *ngIf="questionKey.value", which will display the element if value is true. For a more concrete input run validation on the input box and switch

`*ngIf="questionKey.value" to *ngIf="questionKey.valid"`

This is how I generally do it

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you, but I'm going to learn more about ngControl and test some variants. Thanks.

Comment: I might write a more comprehensive answer later today if I get the time